# Value Displays Blank when I tried to edit in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to edit in laravel

In my controller I have this

```
public function edit(Book $book)
{
    return view ('admin.book.edit')->with('book', $book)->with('authors', Author::all())->with('categories', Category::all());
}
```

In my index view for all books, I have this

```
    <tbody>
        @foreach($books as $book)
         ...
             <td> {{ $book -> name }} </td>
            <td>  
            <a href="{{ route('admin.book.edit',$book->id) }}">
                <button class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
            </a>
            </td>
            ...
```

My Edit view is like this

```
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Book Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="{{ $book->name }}" >
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="about">About the Book </label>
        <textarea name="about" id="about" cols="5" rows="5" class="form-control">{{ $book->about }}</textarea>
    </div>
```

In my web.php

```
Route::get('/admin/book/edit', 'BooksController@edit')->name('admin.book.edit');
```

My table schema

```
Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->text('about');
    ...   
});
```

I was thinking this `value="{{ $book->name }}"` will return the value but it returned blank. Probably I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you don't define in your `route` `Model` bindings:

Change it to, so Laravel knows that the ID you pass in route should return `Book` Model. That you use in your edit function `edit(Book $book)`

```php
Route::get('/admin/book/edit/{book}', 'BooksController@edit')->name('admin.book.edit');
```

Also take a [look](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#resource-controllers) into `Resource Controllers`:

```php
Route::resource('books', 'BooksController');
```

This will generate all routes you need `view/edit/update/delete` Check your routes bu running `php artisan route:list`

Read [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding) for more info

Comment: This is wrong, as this book is a folder inside admin which is inside view folder.Like this
views->admin->book->edit.blade.php. Your answer will return 404. and even if i try 
Route::get('/admin/book/{book}/edit', 'BooksController@edit')->name('admin.book.edit');
It will still return error because this route model binding is for delete

Comment: @xtremeCODE read the docs :) your `views` structure/path has nothing to do with your route path, When you use `edit(Book $book)`, you tell controller to load Specific Book from Database, but in route you don't pass ID. Adding in route `{book}` the URL path will be `/admin/1/edit`: where 1 is the ID of the book in Database.

Comment: I see my error, its suppose to be Route::get('/admin/book/edit/{book}', 'BooksController@edit')->name('admin.book.edit');

Comment: Is exactly what I wrote, just in different place... I just gave you the idea how you need to define your routing, so Model binding will work.

Comment: If you can edit it, I can accept it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Update with extra info

Answer (score 1):

They was an error in my route, so I change to this

```
Route::get('/admin/book/edit/{book}', 'BooksController@edit')->name('admin.book.edit');
```